# new variable in data.table R based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a data set with all football world cup teams with several variables, from year 1930 to 2006, like this:

```
    Year       Team ISO GF GA Penalties Matches SOG SW FK Offside Corners Won Drawn Lost
1: 1930  Argentina  AR 18  9         0       5  18  0  0       0       0   4     0    1
2: 1930    Uruguay  UY 15  3         0       4  15  0  0       0       0   4     0    0
3: 1930        USA  US  7  6         0       3   7  0  0       0       0   2     0    1
4: 1930 Yugoslavia  YU  7  7         0       3   7  0  0       0       0   2     0    1
5: 1930     Brazil  BR  5  2         0       2   5  0  0       0       0   1     0    1
6: 1930      Chile  CL  5  3         0       3   5  0  0       0       0   2     0    1
```

I want to indicate which team was the winner in a given year, i.e. creating a new variable and assigning 1 to the winner and 0 to the other teams, like this:

```
    Year       Team ISO GF GA Penalties Matches SOG SW FK Offside Corners Won Drawn Lost Winner
1: 1930  Argentina  AR 18  9         0       5  18  0  0       0       0   4     0    1      0
2: 1930    Uruguay  UY 15  3         0       4  15  0  0       0       0   4     0    0      1
3: 1930        USA  US  7  6         0       3   7  0  0       0       0   2     0    1      0
4: 1930 Yugoslavia  YU  7  7         0       3   7  0  0       0       0   2     0    1      0
5: 1930     Brazil  BR  5  2         0       2   5  0  0       0       0   1     0    1      0
6: 1930      Chile  CL  5  3         0       3   5  0  0       0       0   2     0    1      0
```

I have a vector with the winners in order and I wanted to do it like this:

```
data[, Winner := ifelse(Team == c("Uruguay", "Italy", "Italy", "Uruguay", "Germany FR", "Brazil", "Brazil", "England", "Brazil", "Germany FR", "Argentina", "Italy", "Argentina", "Germany FR", "Brazil", "France", "Brazil", "Italy"), 1, 0), by = Year]
```

So assigning 1 to Uruguay and 0 to other teams in 1930, 1 to Italy and 0 to other teams in 1934, and so on... But it does not work of course, can you help me how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Your example is not clear.  Can you show a bit more better example with multiple 'Year' and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the issue seems to be that

1. We are using `==` with another vector of different length
2. From the description, we may need to match the winner vector that corresponds to the 'Year' column.

If that is the case, we can either `rep`licate the `vector` of winner names ('team_vec') with the `length` of each 'Year' and then do a `==`

```
library(data.table)
team_vec <-  c("Uruguay", "Italy", "Italy", "Uruguay",
  "Germany FR", "Brazil", "Brazil", "England", "Brazil", 
  "Germany FR", "Argentina", "Italy", "Argentina", "Germany FR", "Brazil", 
             "France", "Brazil", "Italy")


n1 <- data[, .(n = .N), Year]$n
data[, Winner := +(Team %in% rep(team_vec, n1))]
```

---

Or another option is a `join` with 'key' as 'Year'.  For that, we may need to create a `keyvalue` dataset.  Change the values of 'Year' if needed

```
keydat <- data.table(Year = seq(1930, 
     length.out = length(team_vec), by = 1), Team = team_vec)
```

then do the join

```
 data[, Winner := 0]
 data[keydat, Winner := 1, on = .(Team, Year)]
```

Comment: The problem with this, that it assigns 1 to all of the teams in the vector in each year, what I want is to assign 1 only to Uruguay in 1930, only to Italy in 1934, again only to Italy in 1938 and so on. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @john there is a group by 'Year'

Comment: Yes, but it still does not do it like that for some reason. It assigns 1 to Argentina in 1930 as well

Comment: the first solution gives me the same outcome as before and the second solution gives me this error:
Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[2]='V2'

Comment: @john sorry, the second had a typo.  It should be `keydat` in the join.  It is not clear why you got the same output for the first solution.  I `rep`licated` the 'team_vec' based on the frequency of 'Year'.  So, it is doing an elementwise comparison for each 'Year'